# How to create a Google+ page for my website?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-pages

How can I create a page in Google+ for my website?
I want it to have a URL like `plus.google.com/+MyWebsiteName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sign in to your regular G+ account.

- At the bottom of the left panel, click [**Google+ for your brand**](https://plus.google.com/brand).
- On the following screen, click **Create Google+ Page**.
- Create your Brand Account.
- On the following screen, under **Enable Google+ for your brand**, click **Enable**.

([source](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1710600))

In order to get a custom URL, you need to [satisfy some criteria](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2676340) first:

- Have ten or more followers (people who have added you to their circles)
- Account is at least 30 days old and in good standing
- Profile has a profile photo

If you meet the criteria, then you'll see a banner at the top of the screen when signed in to your G+ Brand page.

**Important:** You can’t change your custom URL after you create it, so be sure you like yours before you finalize it.

([source](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2676340))